# getaddrinfo calls assert in the program

Tags: c++, curl, glibc

I am developing a program using the libcurl. The program creates a thread, which in turn makes an HTTP request using libcurl. But sometimes the program crashes with the error

> unexpected error 9 on netlink descriptor

After in curl turned off AsynchDNS. But the problem remains. As I understand the reason for assert is `getaddrinfo`. Maybe to use `getaddrinfo` in multi-threaded applications some kind of initialization is needed? Or is `getaddrinfo` generally non-thread safe?

[image: GDB stack trace]

libcurl version:

> curl 7.67.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.67.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4
>   Release-Date: 2019-11-06
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets

glibc version:

> ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
>   Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>   Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of all that text.  Copy and paste the text into the question.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` is guaranteed to be thread-safe. In fact, its thread safety is one of the reasons (amongst many) why it is preferred over the `gethostby...()` functions, which are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: I wanted to copy, but I only had a screenshot. In a couple of days, the program will crash again, and I will be able to copy the full call stack.

Comment: glib and glibc are two different things, btw.

Answer (score 3):

This is a file descriptor race in the application. The typical scenario for error 9 (`EBADF`) looks like this:

1. Thread A closes a file descriptor.
2. Thread B calls `getaddrinfo` and opens a Netlink socket.  It happens to receive the same descriptor value.
3. Due to a bug, thread A closes the same file descriptor again. Normally, that would be benign, but due to the concurrent execution, the Netlink socket created by glibc is closed.
4. Thread B attempts to use the Netlink socket descriptor and receives the `EBADF` error.

The key to fixing such bugs is figuring out where exactly the double-close happens.

Comment: Do you have anything to contribute as to how to do this? `The key to fixing such bugs is figuring out where exactly the double-close happens.` That is a monumental and vague task. How do you wrap usage so you can determine where the race condition is coming from? Why would it be trying to reuse a descriptor so recently closed instead of providing one that has no risk of this?

Comment: POSIX requires that the lowest available descriptor is used for new descriptors, which tends to maximize the potential for such races. Detecting them is somewhat application-dependent; I would try to come up with a solution based on Systemtap or Dyninst if the application is sufficiently complex.